# How To Add Additional Options In Magento 2 Cart

Tags: magento2, quoteitem

I used this to **Add Additional Options** In **Magento 2 Cart**

> https://livesubwpcache.cloudways.com/blog/add-additional-options-in-magento-2/

But this is working only with Simple product.

For configurable products, I did the following change

```
$item->addOption(array(
    'product_id' => $item->getProductId(),
    'code' => 'additional_options',
    'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
));
```

After that, the `additional_options` going to the cart. But it is not getting saved when complete the order.

seems because of this ….

```
//filter out config/bundle etc product
if(!$item->getParentItemId() && $item->getProductType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
{
    $this->quoteItems[$item->getId()] = $item;
}
```

How can I fix it ? I need this functionality for configurable products.

Answer (score 5):

after `$item->addOption(...)` try calling `$item->saveItemOptions()`.
Also a side note, don't add the options as serialized using `serialize($additionalOptions)`, use `json_encode` or better yet the method `Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json::serialize`.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**: Create registration.php and module.xml file the for custom module.

**Step 2**: Assign Observers to Events

> /app/code/Namespace/Mymodule/etc/events.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_load_after">
        <observer name="set_additional_options" instance="Namespace\Mymodule\Observer\SetAdditionalOptions"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Step 3**: Create the Observers

> app/code/Namespace/Mymodule/Observer/SetAdditionalOptions.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Mymodule\Observer;
 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;
 
class SetAdditionalOptions implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $_request;
     
    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,
        SerializerInterface $serializer
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }
 
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Check and set information according to your need
        if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add') { //checking when product is adding to cart
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            $additionalOptions = [];
            $additionalOptions[] = array(
                'label' => 'Some Label',
                'value' => 'Some Info',
            );
            $observer->getProduct()->addCustomOption('additional_options', $this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions));
        }
    }
}
```

run below command after

```
rm -rf var/di var/generation var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/*

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

reference links

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-additional-options-in-magento-2/

https://webkul.com/blog/additional-options-cart-item-magento2/

https://www.codedecorator.com/blog/how-to-additional-options-in-cart-item-magento2/ (Magento2.4)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still the same issue. The additional options not in the back-end when I order configurable products.

Comment: @SamanthaRajasingha - Can you refer the above both links?

Comment: I used those links already, I got the same issue from there.

Comment: how to add additional options from the controller by item id in magento 2

Comment: @SamanthaRajasingha, have you fixed the issue. I am facing same issue with additional options which is not showing in admin

Answer (score 0):

After add additional options to cart You need to create another observer for save additional attributes order item from quote item.

Please add this event observer code in Module's etc/events.xml

```
<event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
    <observer instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Sales\OrderItemAdditionalOptions" name="vendor_module_observer_sales_model_service_quote_submit_before"/>
</event>
```

Please create observer file in your module

```
Vendor\Module\Observer\Sales\OrderItemAdditionalOptions.php
```

And here is Observer code for save Additional Options to Order Item.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Sales;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
class OrderItemAdditionalOptions implements ObserverInterface
{
public function __construct(
Json $serializer = null
) {    
    $this->serializer = $serializer ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Json::class);
}
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    try {
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $quoteItems = [];

        // Map Quote Item with Quote Item Id
        foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $quoteItem) {
            $quoteItems[$quoteItem->getId()] = $quoteItem;
        }

        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $orderItem) {
            $quoteItemId = $orderItem->getQuoteItemId();
            $quoteItem = $quoteItems[$quoteItemId];
            $additionalOptions = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options');


            if (count($additionalOptions) > 0) {
                // Get Order Item's other options
                $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
                // Set additional options to Order Item
                $options['additional_options'] = $this->serializer->unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
                $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // catch error if any
    }
}
}
```

Please check this I think it will help you.