# How to get custom attributes in cart Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart

I have asked a question and thanks for you I can get the **custom attributes** of simple product but if I added a product from configurable product I can't recuperate the value so what's the problem? Please any help 
[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. so can you please explain in detail

Comment: ok if i visit a page of configurable product and then i choose some options and then add to cart i can't recuperate the value of my new custom attribute in cart

Comment: but if i add a product from simple product it's easy to get the value of my custom attribute in the cart so how to get the value in cart of my custom attribute

Comment: you can see in the screenshot i have 10 for the simple product and null for the fisrt product

Comment: Is the custom attribute assigned to the configurable product(Parent Product) ? if not then please assign it and check

Comment: how to know that

Comment: because in Bo if i want to create a configurable product i can see the atrtribute but he does not have value the child have value but the parent no

Comment: here you can see the first product it's a child of a configurable product  and the options selected are there in cart but how to get this custom attribute

Comment: @DevelopperMagento please try to assign the attribute value to parent product, because in your cart if you add any configurable product and it is showing only parent product data, so you must have to assign custom attribute to your parent product.

Comment: please how to do that

Comment: Edit your parent product, select custom variable from that product, so it will show that custom attribute in your cart page.

Comment: please explain more to me i feel lost sorry

Comment: can understund this point please more expalanation